# How do I use a local Objective-C file in a pod class file I'm editing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have a library that I'm using through Cocoapods, and I'm modifying it slightly. I have a class I've created in my normal project (outside of Cocoapods) that I want to use in the Cocoapod, but when I try to import the file it says that file doesn't exist.

As pods are seemingly achieved through a separate project within the same workspace, I assume that's the reason why I can't access it. How would I access it, however? Do I have to import the file separately into the Pods project and then maintain two separate versions? Or is there a better way?